# Communication codes Xiaomi Scooter

Tags: android, ios, parsing, bluetooth, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to make my *Pebble* application for *Xiaomi Scooter*, but I can not find the codes that this system communicates with the application (`Ninebot App`). Can someone have communication codes for *Xiaomi Scooter*? Can you know how to intercept `Bluetooth` traffic on *MacOS*? Or maybe you have one of the versions of firmware for scooter? On the Internet, I can not find any information on this topic. Thankful in advance for answers.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on extracting the BTLE protocol for the Ninebot as well. The easiest way to do this is on an Android device running the Ninebot app. Put the Android into development mode and then enable Bluetooth logging.

Comment: I will pay you if you share your work with me or at least tell me how to achieve this communication?

Comment: yes I got packets but how to send him to device, it needs `BluetoothSocket` but to get this I need UUID of device, how to get that?